# loopbackjs dynamic datasource

Tags: loopbackjs

Hi I have many MySql server with same schema and differents BDD names.

Each BDD match a customer and for every customer the schema is the same.

I have defined a model in loopback with the properties I want to expose.

Now I want to add remote method with arguments :  database Ip, BDD name that do a find().

After search I have tried to create a new dataSource :

//Find all dataSources of app

```
var dataSrc = loopback.createDataSource({
                connector: 'mysql',
                host: custIp,
                database: bdd,
                username: 'user',
                password: 'pass',
                name: customer
            });
app.dataSource(customer, dataSrc);
```

For every server the user and password are the same.

After that I try to modify the model with this dataSource :

```
loopback.configureModel(this, {dataSource: dataSrc});
```

But after creating the dataSource I see that it is not connected and so the find don't do anything ...

I don't know if I must create also a new model or if I can change only the dataSource of my current model.

In my model JSON I put "base": "Model" and in my model-config.json I put "dataSource": null.

Can anyone have done this ?

Thanks for any answers.